# OS X El Capitan – "package is not compatible" error

Tags: macos, compatibility, pkg

The build machine used in my project is **not** based on OS X El Capitan – it is running **Yosemite**.

So far I've never had problems with the generated installer file (`.pkg`), but on El Capitan, I receive the error `"this package is incompatible with this version of OS X..."`

1. What could be the reasons of such incompatibility? I've found one thread about using SIP protected locations but it doesn't seem to be my issue.
2. Is there any way to verify if my PKG file is compatible with El Capitan without actually having El Capitan installed?

Comment: Like any computer support the only way to be sure is have a copy of the OS - using VMs usually is a good way to check without having lots of hardware

Comment: What tool are you using to build the `pkg`? There are a few formats used for Installer Packages on OS X. Consider updating your tools to build with `productbuild` or `pkgbuild`.

Comment: productbuild and pkgbuild - those are exactly tools I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wonders, on El Capitan installers can't copy files to /usr/bin. That was the reason.

Comment: So were you copying something there using your pkg ??